# How to update backend servers dynamically from an ASG while setting up HAProxy as a Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I have an ASG group in AWS that would run 3-5 instances basis on some parameters. These instances are running Windows servers hosting 3 websites on IIS, and all are running on port 443, which is HTTPS. (All are replicas of one AMI which means only 3 websites are running on all of them to load balance)

Looking at this setup, we are introducing  HAProxy as a load balancer between our customers and the ASG. If the servers were static, then the HAProxy configuration is straightforward and works fine. I can do the load balance by mentioning the IPs of the static servers in the backend section. However, the problem is that since these servers are in ASG, they would scale in and out at anytime. And we want to automate this whole scenario on the HAProxy side.

I learned about **DataPlaneApi**, which can help in the service discovery of AWS; however, we expected it to work differently. I need help finding the proper documentation or a guide explaining this.

Any help from someone is appreciated.

I'm attaching my sample HAProxy config below:

```
  global
  daemon
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
  crt-base /etc/ssl/private
  stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock user haproxy group haproxy mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  stats timeout 30s
  ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
  log /dev/log local0
  log /dev/log local1 notice

# Default SSL material locations
# See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
defaults unnamed_defaults_1
  mode http
  log global
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000
  errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
  errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
  errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
  errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
  errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
  errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

frontend main
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cl-secret1.pem crt /etc/haproxy/cl-secret2.pem
  acl app1 hdr(host) -i cloud-app1.priv.url
  acl app2 hdr(host) -i cloud-app2.priv.url
  use_backend backend1 if app1
  use_backend backend2 if app2

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend backend1
  balance source
  server-template srv 1-5 cloud-app1.priv.url:443


backend backend2
  balance source
  server-template srv 6-10 cloud-app2.priv.url:443
```

Summary of what I need:

I want the data plane API to detect the private IP of instances running in ASG. Those should automatically be added to the backend section in runtime and not manually.

Comment: Why are you reinventing AWS Load Balancers (which I believe use HAProxy behind the scenes) with your own implementation of HAProxy? You're either going to have to place an AWS Load Balancer between your HA Proxy and the auto-scaling group, or just use Amazon's Load Balancer directly.

Comment: @MarkB We are doing this primarily for 2 reasons:
1. Private URL - We are doing all of this for a private URL and there is huge cost associated with the private URLs when it comes to AWS load balancers. They are free for public urls only.
2. To get more control and do extra customizations on the LB level depending on the url that we will be getting which will be defined in the ACLs. Also, we need to monitor the logs with more details for some other purpose.
The above 2 things can't be achieved with the AWS ELB hence we are shifting to our own LB and I think many people does that for control

Comment: AWS Load Balancers cost the same if the are public or private. There is not a huge cost for private URLs with AWS Load Balancers.